# what's the difference between DATEDIFF and doing subtraction by myself

Tags: mysql, sql

**the leetcode question [197.Rising Temperature](https://leetcode-cn.com/problems/rising-temperature/submissions/)**

---

Given a Weather table, write a SQL query to find all dates' Ids with higher temperature compared to its previous (yesterday's) dates.

```
+---------+------------------+------------------+
| Id(INT) | RecordDate(DATE) | Temperature(INT) |
+---------+------------------+------------------+
|       1 |       2015-01-01 |               10 |
|       2 |       2015-01-02 |               25 |
|       3 |       2015-01-03 |               20 |
|       4 |       2015-01-04 |               30 |
+---------+------------------+------------------+
For example, return the following Ids for the above Weather table:

+----+
| Id |
+----+
|  2 |
|  4 |
+----+
```

---

i didn't know the function `DATEDIFF()`,so i wrote my sql solution:

```
select w1.Id
from Weather w1,Weather w2
where w1.RecordDate - w2.RecordDate = 1
and w1.Temperature > w2.Temperature
```

and i went through the testcase but got a wrong submit,the right solution is use funtion `DATEDIFF()`

```sql
select w1.Id
from Weather w1,Weather w2
where DATEDIFF(w1.RecordDate,w2.RecordDate)=1
and w1.Temperature > w2.Temperature
```

so my question is what's the difference between 
`DATEDIFF(w1.RecordDate,w2.RecordDate)=1`and `w1.RecordDate - w2.RecordDate = 1`

thank you for your help

Comment: What is the datatype of `RecordDate`? If it's `DATE` then they should be equivalent. But if it's `DATETIME`, they aren't the same because the subtraction includes the time as well as the date.

Comment: Try this query to see what happens with `DATETIME`: `select cast('2019-03-21' as datetime) - cast('2019-03-11' as datetime);`

Comment: Please post the problem description here. The link requires a login to see the question. It's also in Chinese, we need English here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the datatype of `RecordDate` is `DATETIME` rather than `DATE`, subtracting them returns a large value that contains the difference between the times as well as the dates. E.g.

```
mysql> select cast('2019-03-21 10:20:30' as datetime) - cast('2019-03-11 9:15:20' as datetime) as difference;
+-----------------+
| difference      |
+-----------------+
| 10010510.000000 |
+-----------------+
```

But if they're `DATE` then subtraction should be the same as `DATEDIFF()`:

```
mysql> select cast('2019-03-21' as date) - cast('2019-03-11' as date) as difference;
+------------+
| difference |
+------------+
|         10 |
+------------+
```

Comment: but all the leetcode testcase input is DATE, so it confused me.

Comment: The input is irrelevant, what matters is the datatype. Dates will be converted to datetime if that's what the column is.

Answer (score 2):

When we do simple addition and subtraction on the date or datetime, it will convert it into a number and after that the actual operation will execute. After the operation execution, the output will not be the date datatype.

For example,

---

For addition (+) : -

**'2020-07-31' + 1 => 20200732**

---

For subtraction (-) : -

**'2020-08-01' - '2020-07-31' => 70**

---

It should return 1 but as they consider it as a number so they return 70 instead of 1.

This is the reason we cannot apply direct addition or subtraction on date.

To get the actual difference between two dates one should must use the **DateDiff()**.

```
Datediff(cast('2020-08-01' as Date),Cast('2020-07-31' as Date)) => 1
```

---